# Best practice for storing REST API Url in extjs using Sencha Architect

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I was started developing an application using Extsj in Sencha Architect IDE.
I need to use many REST API request from my application. I was confused about storing the static API URLs in my project. Anyone can suggest a better method to define the API url?

Comment: Why you want to "store" some url. You would be just calling that api whenever needed. I didnt understand sole purpose behind this. Can you plz elaborate ?

Comment: @Tejas I need to store the api base in a constant value